# Extract multiple strings per line separated by special character from a file

Tags: unix, sed, extract

I get a file (FILEMANES.txt) containing file names in a text file. Each line contain one or more file names separated by a #.

```
#filename1#
#filename2#filename3#filename4#
#filename5#filename6#
....
```

In a for loop to browse a directory content, i need to compare each file name found in the directory with each filenameX found FILEMANES.txt

I guess I can do it with sed and/or awk but I miss some skills

If somebody can help it would be great

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Comparing each file to each name would be very slow. Let the tools do some of the work:

```
for file in * ; do
    grep -o "#$file#" FILENAMES.txt
done
```

Or, without a loop:

```
ls | sed 's/^\|$/#/g'| grep -oFf- FILENAMES.txt
```

Note that if the filenames contained spaces and other special characters, the solutions would be more complicated.